# Vb.net Get substring length

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010, programming-languages, substring

Im making a console based programming language and i need help with checking the length of a substring.

The Code:

```
Private Sub DebugToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DebugToolStripMenuItem.Click
    For Each a As String In RichTextBox1.Text.Split(System.Environment.NewLine)
        If (a.Contains("me#write>")) Then
            Console.Write(a.Substring(9))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But if i try to input:

```
me#write>hi
me#write>hello
```

it outputs:

```
Hi
me#write>hello
```

So i need help with ending the substring at the end of the text that the user inputted.

Comment: This is not compilable code.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile so it is difficult to tell what the issue is

Answer (score 2):

Since the line break code in a `RichTextBox` has only LF(Line Feed), so you can't split lines by `Environment.NewLine` which is CRLF on Windows.
Use `Lines` property instead.

```
For Each a As String In RichTextBox1.Lines
    ...
```